# How to solve the first argument must be slice when appending the data

Tags: go

I'm making a query on the basis of the conditions but there is a error in the appending of them the query I'm making is:-

```
query := bson.M{}
query["$or"] = []bson.M{}
if keyword != "" {
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"], bson.M{"author": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}})
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"], bson.M{"title": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}})
}
if types == "" {
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"], bson.M{"type": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + types + ".*", "i"}})
}
if category == "" {
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"], bson.M{"category": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + category + ".*", "i"}})
}
if tag == "" {
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"], bson.M{"tags": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + tag + ".*", "i"}})
}
if len(ids) > 0 {
    query["_id"] = bson.M{"$in": ids}
}
```

There is problem of appending the data with the `query["$or"]`. The error comes out is:-

> first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
>
> first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
>
> first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
>
> first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
>
> first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}

Can anyone tell me that how will I solve this problem.

Comment: Use a slice as the first argument. Why is this confusing?

Comment: What type of slice i have used to make a query. means what correction should be there

Answer (score 3):

Right now you're passing an `interface{}`, as you can see from [the definition of bson.M](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M). So you need to assert that to some type of slice.

You're assigning a slice of type `[]bson.M` to the value earlier, so just assert that type. Example:

```
    query["$or"] = append(query["$or"].([]bson.M), bson.M{"author": bson.RegEx{"(?i).*" + keyword + ".*", "i"}})
```

what would probably be more readable, though, is to assign your calculated value at the end instead:

```
or := []bson.M{}
// ...
    or = append(or, ...)

query["$or"] = or
```